# React.js onclick event: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am a beginner in the react framework, so my question may appear basic to many of you. But believe me I've been stuck on this part.
I am trying to get the text box value on button click and send the value to other function as a prop.
I'm able to extract the value of textbox field but on the click event, i get an error 'Cannot read property 'props' of undefined'.

here are the important points:-

1. termchange() is used for extracting the input text value.
2. handleclick is used for extracting textbox value onclick event.
3. oncitychange is a function to which I've to send the value of textbox 
   (oncitychange() function is inside different component).

Thank you in advance.

here's my code:-

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cityname:''
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <span>Enter the city: </span>
        <input type="text" id="txtbox" value={this.state.cityname} 
          onChange={event=>this.termchange(event.target.value)} />
        <input type="submit" onClick={this.handleclick} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  termchange(cityname){
    this.setState({cityname});
  }

  handleclick(){
    this.props.oncitychange(cityname);
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: while not technically mandatory, generally the render method should be the last method defined, just a style tip

Comment: oh also try binding your methods in your constructor, just add a new line to the constructor and say `this.handleclick = this.handleclick.bind(this)` that should solve your problem hopefully, the issue is that `this` is not pointing to your component but to your method, so you need to bind `this` so that it points to your component instead. You need to reference state in your click handler as well `cityname` should be `this.state.cityname` and when you set state it should be `this.setState{cityname: cityname}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is all about scope. Your functions don't know what `this` is. You can bind `this` in the constructor or other options may be easier depending on your environment.

Add this to your constructor to fix:

`this.termchange = this.termchange.bind(this);
this.handleclick = this.handleclick.bind(this);`

Or read https://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/ for a more detailed explanation of what is going on.

I personally use ES7 fat arrow class methods for the simplicity and I think most developers are moving in that direction.

Comment: wait by `use ES7 fat arrow` do you mean like `handleClick = () => {}`? I did not know that would work that's beautiful

Comment: Yes, no looking back after you discover it

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to fix my problem. After inserting your part in my code, I added 'this.props.oncitychange(this.state.cityname);' under handleClick() function and its working.

Comment: No problem. That makes sense, otherwise `cityname` will be `undefined` (i missed this in my answer as it wasn't what was causing your original error). You had more than one issue with the original code, as SALEH pointed out in other answer's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Add `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)` at constructor

Comment: This will work, I don't know why somebody down-voted it. I voted it back to 0 for you. Additional explanation would be helpful, although it's been explained in the comments on question

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but its not working. 'Uncaught ReferenceError: cityname is not defined' this is the error encountered onClick event.

Comment: Appreciate it [Cory Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/749622/cory-danielsonll)

Comment: that's because you are using `cityname` variable which is not declared in the scope of `handleClick` method. if you want to access state property with this name, replace `cityname` with `this.state.cityname`, or destructure the property to a variable `cityname`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `onClick={this.handleClick}` by:

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

That way, the function scope will be tight to the React object

Comment: I don't think this is right, if you bind at that point, `this` will be pointing to the input element won't it? you should bind in the constructor

Comment: It will work but I believe it is inefficient as it happens every re-render.

Comment: @TravisWhite yeah you're probably right, the bind at constructor might be better

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak it's an arrow function so `this` keeps pointing at the component